# Dialog fails on iOS if the user manually removes my application

Tags: ios, facebook, dialog

I am developing an app for iPhone that allows users to share some photos on FB. It stores the token (and it asks for offline access, so no expiration). My problem is when an user accepts the permissions, then he removes the application from Facebook. My iOS app doesn't "know" about this fact, so isSessionValid returns YES. If I try to open the dialog to post something on user's wall:

[facebook dialog:@"stream.publish" andParams:params andDelegate:appDelegate];

The window opens and it shows "An error has occurred, please try later".

How can I check directly on Facebook if session... ISREALLYvalid (or: how can I display a new request to authorize my app, then continue to the wall post process?)

Thank you in advance!